# Unity: Switching from one FixedUpdate-like coroutine to another one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine `DefaultFixedUpdate()` that functions as a replacement for `FixedUpdate()` and another coroutine called `WallSlidingFixedUpdate()`. I have two variables that store which of the both is active. `activeCoroutine` and `prevActiveCoroutine` with the starting strings `nameof(DefaultFixedUpdate)` and `"no coroutine"`. In `FixedUpdate()` from Unity I have this code that should change coroutines if `activeCoroutine` and `prevActiveCoroutine` are not the same:

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (activeCoroutine != prevActiveCoroutine)
        {
            print($"changing coroutines from {prevActiveCoroutine} to {activeCoroutine}");
            StopCoroutine(prevActiveCoroutine);
            StartCoroutine(activeCoroutine);
            prevActiveCoroutine = activeCoroutine;
            print("changed coroutines");
        }
    }
```

When starting the game `DefaultFixedUpdate()` starts as expected and `prevActiveCoroutine` changes as expected to `activeCoroutine` and when a condition inside `DefaultFixedUpdate()` is met to switch to `WallSlidingFixedUpdate()` `activeCoroutine` changes to the new string as expected. But when `StartCoroutine(activeCoroutine)` gets called the code inside `WallSlidingFixedUpdate()` doesn't run for some reason. `StopCoroutine(prevActiveCoroutine)` does work. The end result is that none of the two corutines runs but expected was that `WallSlidingCoroutine()` runs.

These are the two Coroutines. The changing of `activeCoroutine` happens almost at the bottom of both functions.

```
    IEnumerator DefaultFixedUpdate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //setup
            gravity = (velocity.y < 0 || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) ? dropGravity : normalGravity;
            Vector2 pos = transform.position + col.size.y * 0.5f * Vector3.up;
            Vector2 timeStepVelocity = velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Vector2 pos1 = pos;
            velocity.y -= gravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            //checking collision
            RaycastHit2D[] colChecks = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(pos, col.size, 0, timeStepVelocity, timeStepVelocity.magnitude, 0b1000000);

            //remove unwanted collisions that are behind and don't make sense to collide with
            List<RaycastHit2D> newColChecks = new();
            foreach (RaycastHit2D colCheck in colChecks)
                if (Vector2.Dot(colCheck.normal, timeStepVelocity) < 0)
                    newColChecks.Add(colCheck);
            colChecks = newColChecks.ToArray();

            //remove unwanted velocities
            foreach (RaycastHit2D colCheck in colChecks)
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(colCheck.normal.x / colCheck.normal.y) > 1) // left and right
                {
                    velocity.x = Mathf.Sign(colCheck.normal.x) > 0 ? Mathf.Max(velocity.x, 0) : Mathf.Min(velocity.x, 0);
                }
                else // top bottom
                {
                    velocity.y = Mathf.Sign(colCheck.normal.y) > 0 ? Mathf.Max(velocity.y, 0) : Mathf.Min(velocity.y, 0);
                }
            }

            //calculate correct destination
            if (colChecks.Length == 0)
                pos += timeStepVelocity;
            else
            {
                //create bounding box for all possible future positions
                Vector4 posBox = new Vector4(pos.x, pos.x + timeStepVelocity.x, pos.y, pos.y + timeStepVelocity.y);

                //move to surface
                pos = colChecks[0].centroid;

                //slide along surface until hitting another tangent or the bounding box
                Vector2 tangent = new Vector3(colChecks[0].normal.y, -colChecks[0].normal.x);
                Vector2 centroid = pos;

                //slide until hitting distance bounds
                if (Mathf.Abs(tangent.x) > Mathf.Abs(tangent.y)) //top and bottom
                {
                    pos += tangent / tangent.x * (timeStepVelocity.x - pos.x + pos1.x);
                    tangent = Mathf.Sign(centroid.y - pos1.y) * tangent;
                }
                else //left and right
                {
                    pos += tangent / tangent.y * (timeStepVelocity.y - pos.y + pos1.y);
                    tangent = Mathf.Sign(centroid.x - pos1.x) * tangent;
                }

                //save previous surface that is being slid on
                Vector2 prevTangent = Tangent(colChecks[0].normal);

                //check if I collided with another tangent along the way
                colChecks = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(centroid, col.size, 0, pos, Vector2.Distance(pos, centroid), 0b1000000);

                //remove unwanted collisions that are behind and don't make sense to collide with
                newColChecks = new();
                foreach (RaycastHit2D colCheck in colChecks)
                    if (Vector2.Dot(colCheck.normal, tangent * Mathf.Sign(Vector2.Dot(pos - centroid, tangent))) < 0 || Vector2.Dot(colCheck.normal, timeStepVelocity) < 0)
                        newColChecks.Add(colCheck);
                colChecks = newColChecks.ToArray();

                if (colChecks.Length > 1)
                {
                    pos = centroid + (pos - centroid).normalized * colChecks[1].distance;
                }

                //repeat
                int loopBreak = 0;
                string loopBreakMessage = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    loopBreakMessage += centroid + "\n";
                    if (loopBreak > 4)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("loop limit exceeded\n" + loopBreakMessage);
                        break;
                    }
                    loopBreak++;

                    //check if I collided with another tangent along the way
                    colChecks = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(centroid, col.size, 0, pos - centroid, Vector2.Distance(pos, centroid), 0b1000000);

                    //remove unwanted collisions that are behind and don't make sense to collide with
                    newColChecks = new();
                    foreach (RaycastHit2D colCheck in colChecks)
                        if (Tangent(colCheck.normal) != prevTangent)
                            newColChecks.Add(colCheck);
                    colChecks = newColChecks.ToArray();

                    if (colChecks.Length > 2)
                    {
                        prevTangent = colChecks[0].normal;

                        if (!VectorOnSameQuarter(colChecks[1].normal, colChecks[2].normal)) // stuck in a corner
                        {
                            pos = centroid + (pos - centroid).normalized * colChecks[2].distance;
                            break;
                        }
                        else //continue along new tangent
                        {
                            //corner pos
                            centroid += (pos - centroid).normalized * colChecks[2].distance;
                            //end pos if there's no surface along the way
                            pos = PosAlongVectorInsideRectangle(posBox, centroid, Tangent(colChecks[2].normal));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                AlignVelocityWithGround();
            }

            //check if player is grounded and save ground tangent to remove small hops when going down slopes
            PlayerState.OnGround = false;
            RaycastHit2D[] jumpChecks = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(pos, col.size, 0, Vector2.down, 1e-3f, 0b1000000);
            if (jumpChecks.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (RaycastHit2D jumpCheck in jumpChecks)
                {
                    if (jumpCheck.normal.y > Mathf.Abs(jumpCheck.normal.x))
                    {
                        PlayerState.OnGround = true;
                        groundTangent = new Vector2(jumpCheck.normal.y, -jumpCheck.normal.x);
                    }
                }
                PlayerState.state = PlayerState.state == PlayerState.State.WallSliding ? PlayerState.State.Default : PlayerState.state;
                //check for a wall slide and save wall tangent for smooth sliding
                if (!PlayerState.OnGround && velocity.y < 0 && Mathf.Abs(jumpChecks[0].normal.x) > Mathf.Abs(jumpChecks[0].normal.y) && Mathf.Asin(jumpChecks[0].normal.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg < 15)
                {
                    groundTangent = new Vector2(jumpChecks[0].normal.y, -jumpChecks[0].normal.x);
                    transform.position = pos - col.size.y * 0.5f * Vector2.up;
                    activeCoroutine = nameof(WallSlidingFixedUpdate);
                    yield break;
                }
            }

            transform.position = pos - col.size.y * 0.5f * Vector2.up;
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }
    IEnumerable WallSlidingFixedUpdate()
    {
        print("wallsliding coroutine entered");
        while (true)
        {
            print("wallsliding coroutine happening");

            Vector2 pos = transform.position;

            pos -= Time.fixedDeltaTime * wallSlideSpeed * groundTangent / groundTangent.y;

            transform.position = pos;

            if (InputManager.Left && groundTangent.y > 0)
            {
                activeCoroutine = nameof(DefaultFixedUpdate);
                yield break;
            }
            else if (InputManager.Right)
            {
                activeCoroutine = nameof(DefaultFixedUpdate);
                yield break;
            }
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `stop active; start prev; swap prev, active;`

Comment: Should both `xxxFixedUpdate` methods be coroutines?

Comment: you said that the ```prevActiveCoroutine``` contains string ```"no coroutine"``` and activeCoroutine  contains ```nameof(DefaultFixedUpdate)```.  I don't get it, why are we expecting that your  ```WallSlidingFixedUpdate``` be called at all? It is neither in prev coroutine nor in active one.

Comment: maybe add  ```print($"new active coroutine is {activeCoroutine}");``` to check that you did actually assign your expected coroutine to ```activeCoroutine```?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN there's a conditional statement in ```DefaultFixedUpdate()``` that sets ```activeCoroutine``` to ```nameof(WallSlidingFixedUpdate)```. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @shingo yes, my goal is to switch back an forth between the two coroutines when needed and if a switch isn't needed the active coroutine should just loop until stopped

Comment: @defaultUsernameN the assignment of strings is correct. that is definite. I checked that already.

Comment: Could you show both the code that assigns ```nameof(WallSlidingFixedUpdate)``` to active coroutine and the ```WallSlidingFixedUpdate``` method itself? The part you provided in the question looks fine to me, maybe there is something else missing. Also, does the ```print("changed coroutines");``` statement run after changing to ```WallSlidingFixedUpdate```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248168/discussion-between-krum-3-and-defaultusernamen).

Answer (score 1):

You figured your issue about the return type out already -> It needs to be `IEnumerator`.

Anyway my question is **WHY?**

Instead of going through all that trouble for switching between different Coroutine instances via a `string` I would rather have only a single outer scope routine running and then rather switch between which inner block to execute

```
private enum RoutineType
{
    Default,
    WallSliding
}

private RouineType activeRoutine;

private IEnumerator FixedUptadeRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        switch(activeRoutine)
        {
            case RoutineType.WallSliding:
                yield return DefaultRoutine();
                break;

            case default:
                yield return WallSlidingRoutine();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator DefaultRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // NOTE: Btw you want to wait for fixed update FIRST
        // Before applying all the values

        ...

        // And now this will simply make sure you change the routine type
        activeRoutine = RoutineType.WallSliding;
        // and exit this one so the outer routine will handle the switch in the next frame
        yield break;

        ...
    }
}

private IEnumerator WallSlidingRoutine()
{
    ...
}
```

you can simply `yield return` any `IEnumerator` so it will be executed and at the same time the outer routine waits for it to finish. There is no need to have multiple start and stop coroutines.

Comment: I only started the thing with the strings because of my problem. I first thought you couldn't start a coriutine inside of another one. Meanwhile I've already got rid of the strings but I don't use yield return whateverCoroutine because I want it to start at the beginning so I just do StartCoroutine(whateverCoroutine) and then yield break

Comment: You don't do `yield return someCorotuine` you do `yield return someIEnumerator` which will always start it from the beginning... My point is that you don't have to start and stop any coroutine at all if you simply only split one big routine out into different enumerators

Comment: I mean when I go back to the original coroutine I want to start at the beginning. with yield break, it breaks the while loop and ends the coroutine, so when I comeback to it, it starts at the beginning.

Comment: @KRUM3 yes .. and the same happens using `yield return someIEnumerator;` ..

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly, how did I miss this. The return value of `WallSlidingFixedUpdate` is `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerator`. I changed it to `IEnumertor` and now it works.